# Production angular app shows as Test Mode on Google search

Tags: angular, azure, deployment, google-search

I have a live production angular website with a domain purchased from GoDaddy and hosted as an app service on Azure.

When I search my app on Google, it shows as Test Mode on all pages. Not sure why?

Search Keyword : thinknoblehouse

Answer (score 0):

I had to post the same on Google community forums and an expert helped removed what Google was picking from a cache.

Also had several links that app contained that had to be redirected with 302 because they were modified.